# MVC C#: Use same List of objects in different Models (Reference?)

Tags: model-view-controller, list, pointers, reference, model

I want to use the same list of object in different models. The MainModel should take care about the content of the list so the SubModels using that list get the change as well.

Given following Model 'Customer'...

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer(List<Customer> customerList)
    {
        this.CustomerList= customerList;
        this.CustomerAge= new CustomerAge(this.CustomerList);
    }

    public List<Customer> CustomerList
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public AgeCustomer AgeCustomer
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void SetCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList)
    {
        this.CustomerList= customerList;
    }
}
```

And the Model `CustomerAge`:

```
public class CustomerAge
{
    List<Customer> customerListComplete;

    public CustomerAge(List<Customer> customerList)
    {
        this.customerListComplete= customerList;

    }

    public List<Customer> CustomerListAgeOver40
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerListComplete.Where(c => c.age > 40).ToList();
        }
    }

    public List<Customer> CustomerListAgeUnder40
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerListComplete.Where(c => c.age < 40).ToList();
        }
    }

    public List<Customer> CustomerListAgeEquals40
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customerListComplete.Where(c => c.age = 40).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty simple so far, I have a main model called `Customer` and a helper model called `CustomerAge`. When I change the `CustomerList` in `Customer` by calling `Customer.SetCustomerList(newCustomerList)`, I thought that the `CustomerListComplete` in `CustomerAge` would change as well, but it dosen't. Why? How can I use the same list in both of models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your collection is referenced by, well, references.

`CustomerList` in `Customer` and `customerListComplete` in `CustomerAge` are just 'pointers' to a collection. When you changes `CustomerList`, `customerListComplete` doesn't change.

You need to add `public void SetCustomerList(List<Customer> customerList)` to `CustomerAge` and call it from `Customer.SetCustomerList`.

Other solution is to change `CustomerAge` constructor to get the instance of `Customer` and then use `Customer.CustomerList`:

```
public Customer(List<Customer> customerList)
{
    this.CustomerList= customerList;
    this.CustomerAge= new CustomerAge(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I took the second solution. I think, one more solution would be to change `SetCustomerList()`: `this.CustomerList.Clear()` and then `this.CustomerList.AddRange(customerList)` so I don't change the reference but the content of the reference. Am I right?